# restrict fields according to user permissions in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API using Django rest framework. I have to restrict access to fields (both read or write access) according to the kind of user logged in. How do I go about it ? I'm considering writing separate serializers for different user roles
 (I will get an access token with every request using which I can authenticate the user, the next step will get me the user's roles, according to which I want to restrict what fields the user can see/edit).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django rest framework, use different serializers in the same ModelViewSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to give certain users model level permissions to conduct certain actions you can do this with [custom permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724265/how-to-add-custom-permission-to-the-user-model-in-django?rq=1) like so:

```
class T21Turma(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_view_boletim", "Can view boletim"),
                       ("can_view_mensalidades", "Can view mensalidades"),)
```

Then you can either make several serializers and swap them out in the views based on the permissions, or you can modify the fields of the serializer [dynamically](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields).